# Como hago para saltar de línea en el editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle

me gustaria salatr de línea en el editor en python, NO ME REFIERO A '\n', sino a saltar de línea en el editor, p.e:

```
lista1=['frase','frase2','comienzo frase 3 (aqui meteria el saldo de linea)
final de la frase 3']

if 'resuelto':
    print('muchas gracias')
else:
    print('gracias por intentarlo')
```

Answer (score 2):

Python admite que una cadena pueda separarse en varias líneas si la encierras entre triple comillas.

En tu caso:

```
lista1=['frase', 'frase2', '''comienzo frase 3
final de la frase 3''']
```

No obstante, no tengo claro si es esto lo que quieres hacer, ya que en este caso, el retorno de carro que has metido en el editor tras el 3 queda formando parte de la cadena. Es decir, la tercera cadena de la lista sería equivalente a `'comienzo frase 3\nfinal de la frase 3'`, de modo que si haces un `print(lista1[2])`, te sale la frase en dos líneas, partida por el punto donde la partiste en el editor.

Si lo que quieres es partirla en el editor pero *sin que afecte* a la cadena almacenada (es decir, que la cadena no tenga ese salto de línea) lo que puedes hacer es aprovecharte de una característica de python que consiste en que si ve dos cadenas seguidas, sin un operador en medio, las concatena. Por ejemplo:

```
ej = 'Hola' 'mundo'
```

tiene el resultado de que `ej` contiene `'Holamundo'`. Y lo mismo si entre las cadenas hay un retorno de carro, siempre que ambas estén dentro de una expresión multi-linea como pueda ser algo entre paréntesis o entre corchetes. Por ejemplo:

```
ej = ('Hola'
      'mundo')
```

De nuevo produce el mismo resultado que `ej='Holamundo'`. Fíjate que no he puesto comas entre una cadena y otra (pues eso daría como resultado una tupla con dos elementos), sino simplemente retornos de carro y espacios que son ignorados por el intérprete, el cual concatenará las dos cadenas porque aparecen "seguidas" (una vez ignorados espacios y retornos de carro).

En tu caso podrías por tanto hacer:

```
lista1=['frase', 'frase2', 'comienzo frase 3'
        'final de la frase 3']
```

Ya que entre la cadena `'comienzo frase 3'` y la cadena `'final de la frase 3'` no hay comas ni nada salvo espacios y retornos de carro, para Python son una sola cadena igual a `'comienzo frase 3final de la frase 3'`.  En este caso además no necesitas poner nada entre paréntesis porque los corchetes que delimitan la lista ya sirven para crear el grupo.

**Observa** que este truco te permite meter espacios en el editor para hacer una indentación más legible, sin que esos espacios vayan a la cadena. Si en cambio, usando la triple comilla, hubiera indentado para que quedara mejor en el editor:

```
lista1=['frase', 'frase2', '''comienzo frase 3
         final de la frase 3''']
```

todos esos espacios que usé para indentar forman parte de la cadena, que sería ahora `'comienzo frase 3\n         final de la frase 3'`.

Por esta razón, aún si lo que quieres es que el retorno de carro forme parte de la cadena, yo no usaría la triple comilla, que te obliga a "romper" la indentación del código. En su lugar puedes usar esto:

```
lista1=['frase', 'frase2', 'comienzo frase 3\n'
        'final de la frase 3']
```

que usa el truco de concatenar dos cadenas seguidas, pero la primera incluye un `\n`.

Comment: Graias abulafia, al final averigüe otra forma de hacerlo usando '\'    print('muchas\ gracias!!')

Answer (score 1):

Bueno resulta que ya encontre la forma de hacerlo, en una lista podemos usar '\' para partir una frase en 2 lineas, ej:

```
lista1=['hola muy\
buenos días']
```

para diviidir elementos de una lista en 2 lineas haremos:

```
lista1=['hola'\
'buenos dias']
```

de la primera forma, el mismo elemento queda dividio en dos lineas, de la segunda, los elementos de la lista quedan divididos en 2.

Comment: Si pones el \ dentro de la cadena (primer caso), eso "ignora" el retorno de carro que va luego, por tanto te sirve para separarla en dos lineas, pero no es amigable con la indentación, pues si añades espacios por la izquierda en la segunda línea, esos espacios van a la cadena. Si el \ lo pones entre cadenas dentro de la lista (segundo caso), es equivalente a mi solució, pues dentro de la lista no hace falta "proteger" el retorno de carro. La expresión puede ocupar varias líneas gracias que va entre corchetes.